# In swift, why do I HAVE to use IBaction or IBOutlet to communicate between code and UI?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uibutton, uilabel

I'm new to programming, and I'm trying to understand this concept in Swift IOS. What are the benefits of HAVING to use IBaction and IBoutlet to connect things like UIButtons and UILabels to my code?

Why don't they just let us set UI objects equal to a name like button1 or label1 so we can use those names to call and mutate them in my code?

Comment: Basically, they are just names. Thanks to the Obj-C runtime, the nib loading mechanism can set your ivars based on the outlet name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. IBAction and IBOutlet is how storyboard and xib files created with Interface Builder (IB) link to the implementation files when unarchiving the XML dictionaries of the nibs. However, creating views and controllers with layouts in code is entirely permitted and even a common pattern for project management in teams.

Personally, I do like using Interface Builder for the visual aspect of laying out my views, and it helps reduce the size of my controller files because it allows me to put my layout and color settings into Storyboards and xibs. But, some developers will argue this is actually a drawback, since it obfuscates some of the functionality of your controllers from the uninitiated. There are strong arguments for avoiding the use of Interface Builder when working in teams, but it really boils down to strategy and preference.

Answer (score 2):

They're just tags Xcode uses to link the code and the storyboard / XIB. Functionally they do nothing. They help you as the developer to know what is / isn't / can / can't be connected between the visual representation of your UI and the code driving it.